# Can no longer access files from shared folder or SQL server using Python after updating password on Windows 10?

Tags: python, sql-server, connection

I have a script that I run in Jupyter Notebook every week that requires connecting to MSSQL and accessing files from a shared folder. I have never had problems doing this before, however, I recently had to update my Windows password. Since then, I've been having these issues.

When trying to connect to the MSSQL server I get the error:

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL 
Server Network Interfaces: The logon attempt failed\r\n (-2146893044) 
(SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot 
generate SSPI context (-2146893044); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for 
SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The logon attempt failed\r\n 
(-2146893044); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot 
generate SSPI context (-2146893044)')
```

When trying to access a  file on the shared folder I get:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 
"Sorry, we couldn't find {file} Is it possible it was moved, renamed or 
deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

or

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: {file}
```

However, if I manually navigate to these folders/files I don't have any issues and if I sign into the MSSQL server using Windows Authentication I don't have any issues either. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
This is the command I use to connect:

```
con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',server = '{server}', database = '{database}')
cursor = con.cursor()
```

and I just use

```
pd.read_excel({file_path})
```

to get the file.

Comment: How the script is executed? Is it using task scheduler for example?

Comment: I just run through each of the cells in the jupyter notebook file